# iFrames to create a template

Tags: html, frame

Hi I want to create a website which has the following structure:

[image]

The idea is to have a menu in the left and border images in the left and right frames. the header will contain the page title and also user information (i.e. logged in, log out button etc). The content region is the one where the site content is displayed. I want to only update this as buttons are pressed in the menu in the left frame...

How can I achieve this using iframes? Sorry I am a HTML noob.... Are frames the best approach? I just want to have a part of the page that updates as opposed to the entire page redrawing each time..

Comment: I wouldnt go down that road. A part HTML, what are you using ?

Comment: I am using php,html, jquery and ajax for the front end

Comment: then you really shouldn't go down that road. Use CSS and javascript ...

Answer (score 0):

Actually frames are NOT a good approach. You should avoid frames and completely forget about their existence if possible. [Frames are evil.](http://apptools.com/rants/framesevil.php)

Better approach is use of a preprocessor (PHP, ASP, Python,..) to include parts of the page into HTML. There are many frameworks and templating systems which will do the hard work for you. E.g. for PHP see [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) temlating engine.

If you don't want browsers to reload all page but only content in the middle of the page [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) is much better solution.

**Update:**

In jQuery you could use [jQuery.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) and [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) functions to load and place new content into page when a user clicks on a menu item.

Best practice when using ajax to load new content dynamically is to provide also alternative for machines with disabled JavaScript (e.g. search engines crawlers). However it's bit more complicated to implement this properly from a scratch, but there are some frameworks which can help you. Personally I prefer [Nette Framework](http://doc.nette.org/en/ajax) because it's lightweight and efficient in comparison to other frameworks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..can u give me a link on how to use ajax/jquery to update a div's contents?

Comment: @user559142 I've updated the answer with some more information.